# Pause and Resume Game on app lunch / exit from app ( SpriteKit Swift)

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift2

i have button pause in game and it works well! 
but i need that my game will do pause when I'm exit from app or lunch app again.

i want that the screen is opened when I'm touch on the button pause will open when I'm return my game

how to do it correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should see  https://github.com/aaronabentheuer/AAWindow  this  project. 
first you should add  open AppDelegate.swift and

```
var window: UIWindow? = {
    let window = AAWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds, cornerRadius: 8)
    return window
    }()
```

after than this code add your project

```
func NC()

{
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), usingBlock: { notification in
    })
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName("applicationWillResignActiveWithoutControlCenter", object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), usingBlock: { notification in
        //code
    })
}
func CC()
{
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName("applicationWillResignActiveWithControlCenter", object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), usingBlock: { notification in
  //code
    })
}
func opened()
{
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), usingBlock: { notification in
        // code
    })
}
```

and create new swift file and add this code

```
import UIKit

class AAWindow: UIWindow {


private var activeCornerRadius : CGFloat = 0
private var inactiveCornerRadius : CGFloat = 0
private var cornerRadiusAnimationDuration : Double = 0.15

private var willOpenControlCenter : Bool = false
private var controlCenterOpened : Bool = false
var timer : NSTimer = NSTimer()

private var applicationWillResignActiveWithControlCenterNotification = NSNotification(name: "applicationWillResignActiveWithControlCenter", object: nil)

private var applicationWillResignActiveWithoutControlCenterNotification = NSNotification(name: "applicationWillResignActiveWithoutControlCenter", object: nil)

init(frame: CGRect, cornerRadius: Float) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.clipsToBounds = true
    self.layer.cornerRadius = inactiveCornerRadius

    activeCornerRadius = CGFloat(cornerRadius)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "applicationDidBecomeActive:", name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "applicationWillResignActive:", name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

@objc private func applicationDidBecomeActive (notification : NSNotification) {

    if (controlCenterOpened) {
        controlCenterOpened = false
    } else {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = activeCornerRadius

    }
}
@objc private func applicationWillResignActive (notification : NSNotification) {

    if (willOpenControlCenter) {

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(applicationWillResignActiveWithControlCenterNotification)

        willOpenControlCenter = false
        controlCenterOpened = true
    } else {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(applicationWillResignActiveWithoutControlCenterNotification)

        self.layer.cornerRadius = inactiveCornerRadius
    }
}

private var touchLocation : CGPoint = CGPoint()

override func sendEvent(event: UIEvent) {
    super.sendEvent(event)

    if (event.type == UIEventType.Touches) {
        for touchevent in event.allTouches()! {
            let touch = touchevent

            if (touch.phase == UITouchPhase.Began && touch.locationInView(self).y - self.frame.height * 0.9 >= 0) {
                willOpenControlCenter = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: in this project when you exit from app "application is inactive" so you should do pause game like this project.

Comment: Ok i will try it, but what with resume?